# Getting the absolute path of file downloaded through a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, download

I am developing a chrome extension which downloads particular files from webpages. And I have a popup.html through which I can enter a name for the file to be downloaded and also a link "History" on clicking which I would like to open a new page with links to previously downloaded files(Download history).

I am able to download files but I am unable to figure out how to show the download history. If I could get the absolute path of the file download, I can just put it in the new page as a link. And when we click that the local browser would do the rest(Show the files present in the downloads path).Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [chrome.downloads.DownloadItem](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads#type-DownloadItem), you can use

```
chrome.downloads.DownloadItem.filename
```

to get absolute local path.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked. I should have read the chrome developer properly before putting the question here.