# Get Absolute path for downloaded file in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I need absolute path for the files that i have downloaded through my chrome extension. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35375892/getting-the-absolute-path-of-file-downloaded-through-a-chrome-extension)  post mention a solution by using chrome.downloads.DownloadItem.filename but when i tried using the this, it gives me following error.

> uncaught_exception_handler:8 Error in event handler for downloads.onDeterminingFilename: TypeError: Cannot read property 'filename' of undefined
>       at chrome-extension:/background.js:165:51handler @ uncaught_exception_handler:8(anonymous function) @ uncaught_exception_handler:100EventImpl.dispatch_ @ event_bindings:376dispatchArgs @ event_bindings:243massage_determining_filename @ downloads:54dispatchEvent @ extensions::event_bindings:250

is chrome.downloads.DownloadItem.filename still being supported or i am doing something wrong?

**Update:**

```
**Permission in my manifest.json**
 "permissions": [
    "downloads",
    "tabs"  ]
```

background.js:

```
chrome.downloads.download({url:"http://myserver.com/123.html"},function (id){ 
    console.log( chrome.downloads.id.filename );
    LOG(id);});
```

Comment: Do i need extra permission other than download?

Comment: please show us some sample code where you call this function

Comment: Probably you should try `chrome.downloads[id]` instead of `chrome.downloads.id` ?

Comment: tried console.log( chrome.downloads[id].filename );
 console.log(chrome.downloads.DownloadItem.filename);
 both throws exception.

Answer (score 1):

The filename happens in a later callback. Look for the onProgress onChanged etc type chrome.download.* callbacks and in one of them the filename will appear.