# How to use chrome.downloads.downloaditem.filename?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, download

I am developing an chrome extension, and the working is:

1. whenever any file is downloaded from browser than extension will know that file has been downloaded
2. extension will also have downloaded file path.

For **2 point** to know file path [Getting the absolute path of file downloaded through a chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35375892/getting-the-absolute-path-of-file-downloaded-through-a-chrome-extension) gives answer to use `chrome.downloads.DownloadItem.filename` but I don't know how to implement it.

And still looking for answer for **1 point**

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: For point 1 I have tried ```chrome.downloads.onDeterminingFilename.addListener(function(item, __suggest)``` but it takes file details during download not after. I want my extension to know that something has been downloaded and for point 2 I have came to know to use ```chrome.downloads.DownloadItem.filename``` (but the question is how?)